# System verilog difference in declaration of multibit logic and array logic

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am new to system verilog and having trouble with finding any source so.

When I write

```
logic [3:0] buttonsInc;
```

and after

```
assign buttonsInc[0] = 0;
assign buttonsInc[1] = 0;
```

I get an error saying can not index into non array type... I assume because buttonsInc is a 4 bit number now, not an array. How should I write it to declare an array,say that holds 3 4 bit arrays?
like this maybe?

```
logic[0:3][4:0] buttonsInc;
```

or

```
logic[4:0][3:0] buttonsInc;
```

Also what is the difference between  `[0:3]` and `[3:0]` in defining logic?

Comment: Your three statements look fine. That code should work. Therefore I suspect something else is going on so please show us ALL the code.

Comment: Also, it's very unusual to continuously assign a constant `0` to a variable. Also see this: https://verificationacademy.com/forums/ovm/difference-between-packed-and-unpacked-arrays#reply-31816

Comment: [0:3] and [3:0]  define the order of the numbered bit in the slice. so, for `4'b1010` in the first case buttonInc[0] will be lerftmost '1', whether in the second it will be  rightmost '0'.

Answer (score 0):

logic [3:0]buttons_inc implies a 4 bit vector named buttons_inc, [3:0] signifies that the index 3 (0 to 3) is the MSB bit, whereas [0:3] signifies that index 0 is the MSB bit.
[3:0]--> (MSB)3 2 1 0 ||| [0:3]--> 3 2 1 0(MSB)

logic[3:0][4:0]buttons_inc will create a packed array i.e. 4 vectors each 5 bit wide. Note that packed arrays are essentially vectors which are subdivided into smaller sub_vectors unlike unpacked arrays which are contiguous.